# Coco2d add UIalert or UITextField,first time can show normal ,but next show will badly show two times

Tags: ios, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

Coco2d add UIalert,first time can show normal ,but next show will badly show two times,and when i add  UITextField to cocos2d for input  player information,when I leave this scene ,I 'm
sure UITextField have been release ,but in other scene this UITextField still on the screen

Comment: you might want to share some code

Comment: did you remove the alert view before switching scenes? Cocos2D doesn't clean up UIKit for you.

Answer (score 0):

problem with UIAlert? I used it in many times in iOS game. Worked fine

```
UIAlertView* alert= [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Not Enough Coins!"
                                                message: @"You need more Coins"
                                               delegate: nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] autorelease];
[alert show];
```

For other UI elements, release it on leaving.

```
-(void)onExit
{
   if(mytextBox)
   {
      [mytextBox removeFromSuperview];
   }
   [super onExit];
}
```